# Why if there is no break this code keep returning my input?

Tags: python-3.x, function, break

Could anyone help me to understand why if I didn't put `break` there, the code give me multiple output. For example:

> In : myfunc('abogoboga')
>
> Out : 'aBoGoBoGaaBoGoBoGaaBoGoBoGaaBoGoBoGaaBoGoBoGaaBoGoBoGaaBoGoBoGaaBoGoBoGaaBoGoBoGa'

```
def myfunc(*args):
    output = []
    for strg in args:
        for char in strg:
            for i in range(len(strg)):
                if i % 2 == 0:
                    output.append(strg[i].lower())
                else:
                    output.append(strg[i].upper())
            break
    return ''.join(output)
```

but, after putting `break`  as above:

> In : myfunc('abogoboga')
>
> Out : 'aBoGoBoGa'

Comment: ..which also means that `for char in strg:` loop in your code is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your nested `for` loops accomplish the same thing. `for char in strg` is assigning `char` to each character in `strg`, but you never use it. Instead, you iterate over `strg` again, and the reason it works with the break is that if you break after performing one loop of `for char in strg`, you are turning the `for` loop into a simple statement. A simpler way of doing this is removing `for char in strg`:

```
def myfunc(*args):
    output = []
    for strg in args:
         for i in range(len(strg)):
             if i % 2 == 0:
                 output.append(strg[i].lower())
             else:
                 output.append(strg[i].upper())
    return ''.join(output)
```

Comment: Thank you man @A.J.Uppal . Do you have any recommendation to learn Python for a beginner like me?